# An optimized way to get the maximum sum of subrectangle in a matrix using c++

Tags: algorithm

I have a problem in this code it works well if the dimensions of the matrix is small but it does not respond if the dimensions is large for example 50X50. And the expected input for these dimensions in the problem statement is up to 1000X1000. Any idea?

this is my code: `1-`http://ideone.com/BJuLQh

Comment: what do you mean by maximum sum of subrectangle ?

Comment: You're using an O(n^4) algorithm, so for large n the program becomes very slow and inefficient - think of a smarter way to solve this.

Comment: Include the code in the question itself.

Comment: please clarify the problem you are asking , what  do you mean by maximum sum of a subrectangle ? And as far as i can see a DP approach will work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `O(n^3)` algorithm :-

```
1. fix two columns (u,v) which are end of the rectangle.
2. take sum of row i within (u,v) in sum[i] in ascending order.
3. Use kadane's algorithm on sum[] 
4. The solution will will give you two row values (i,j) and max sum.
5. So you current best rectangle is (i,u),(j,v).
6. Update global max sum if needed.
```

**Time complexity :-**

```
Kadane's algorithm : O(N)
sum of row's i  within (u,v) can be evaluated in O(N) using previous values.
Total : O(N^3) for all (u,v) pairs.
```

[Kadane's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem)